# Can I use only certain numbers from data file in gnuplot title?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with many columns of data and the first two lines look like this:

```
#time a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 d2 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I would like to put a title on the graph which reads like this:

```
a1=2, a2=6, b1=3, b2=7, c1=4, c2=8, d1=5, d2=9
```

So, basically just taking the data from the first line and adding some text with it.  Is this possible?

Thanks mgilson!  Here is the script (the first part.)

```
#filename = "a6_a.txt"

//defining variables called ofac and residual

unset multiplot
set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman,18" 

set lmargin 1
set bmargin 1
set tmargin 1
set rmargin 1
set multiplot
set size 0.8,0.37

set origin 0.1,0.08  #bottom
 set xlabel "time" offset 0,1  #bottom

 set ylabel "{/Symbol w}_i - {/Symbol w}_{i+1}"
 set yrange [-pi:pi]
 plot filename using 1:(residual($7 -$14)) ti "" pt 1 lc 2, \
            "" using 1:(residual($14-$21)) ti "" pt 1 lc 3, \
            "" using 1:(residual($21-$28)) ti "" pt 1 lc 4

set origin 0.1,0.36 #mid
 set format x ""    #mid, turn off x labeling
 set xlabel ""      #mid
 set ylabel "P_{i+1}/P_i" offset 2,0
 set yrange [*:*]
 plot filename using 1:(($10/ $3)**1.5) ti "P_2/P_1" pt 1 lc 2, \
            "" using 1:(($17/$10)**1.5) ti "P_3/P_2" pt 1 lc 3, \
            "" using 1:(($24/$17)**1.5) ti "P_4/P_3" pt 1 lc 4


set origin 0.1,0.64 #top
 set ylabel "semi-major axes"
 set yrange [*:*]
 plot filename using 1:($3):($4*$3) with errorbars ti "" pt 1 lc 1, \
   "" using 1:($10):($10*$11) with errorbars ti "" pt 1 lc 2, \
   "" using 1:($17):($17*$18) with errorbars ti "" pt 1 lc 3, \
   "" using 1:($24):($24*$25) with errorbars ti "" pt 1 lc 4

unset multiplot
unset format 
unset lmargin
unset bmargin
unset rmargin
unset tmargin
```

Comment: Which version of gnuplot do you have?

Comment: It's version 4.4.  I'm running Mac OS X

Comment: Do you have any control over the datafile format?

Comment: I technically do but I would much rather not alter the data file if at all possible.  I could make a separate one though I suppose.

Comment: and just to be clear, you want the *title* to have those numbers, not the key.

Answer (score 0):

You probably *could* do this using gnuplot only (I think), but it would be painful.  The easiest solution is to write an external script which will format the title for you -- e.g. in python (untested):

```
#python script formatTitle.py
import sys
fname=sys.argv[1]
with open(fname,'r') as f:
    line1=f.readline().split()
    line2=f.readline().split()

pairs=sorted(zip(line1,line2)[1:])
print (", ".join("%s=%s"%(p[0],p[1]) for p in pairs))
```

and then in gnuplot:

```
set title "`python formatTitle.py datafile.dat`"
```

**EDIT**

Your script above has a few problems.  First, `//` is not a comment character in gnuplot -- so that will raise some sort of syntax error right away.  Next, you're using `filename` as a string variable (which is OK) but you've not defined it anywhere.  (the first line of your script would probably work except that it has been commented out).  Finally, I can't check since I don't have your datafile, but your use of `lmargin` etc + `set size` + `set origin` is a little hard (for me) to track.  Someone smarter would probably have no problem with it.  When I want to explicitly align my plots however, I use the second form of `margin`.

```
#make plots go from 0.1 to 0.9 on the screen (screen range is 0-1)
# (0,0) is the lower left corner, (1,1) is the upper right.
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.9
```

And then for each of your sub-plots, you can do:

```
NPLOTS=3
SCREENSIZE=0.8  #leave .1 for the top and bottom border
DY=SCREENSIZE/NPLOTS #height of each plot

#bottom
set tmargin at screen 0.9-2*DY
set bmargin at screen 0.9-3*DY
#other commands
plot ... 

#middle
set tmargin at screen 0.9-DY
set bmargin at screen 0.9-2*DY
#other commands ...
plot ...

#top
set tmargin at screen 0.9
set bmargin at screen 0.9-DY
#other commands ...
plot ...
```

Of course, you can play around with the positions as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response!  Scripting it that way makes sense.  Just to be clear, where would it need to be located in the .gnu file?  I probably should have said that I"m using a script to plot. I think my confusion is arising from the script since I did not write it and am brand new to gnuplot. I really would like the info to just be displayed in the bottom left or top left corner. I said title because I finally managed to create a title even though it was in a strange location. Previously I could not even successfully create a label. I have googled this stuff for hours.

Comment: The general things that are supposed to work are not working I think because this script is somewhat specialized.  Is there a way I can attach it?

Comment: @whatsherface : can you post the script as you have it?  I could take a look and probably infer what you want...  As it is, you'd want to place the `set title` before you issue a `plot` or `splot` command.

Comment: I would really like to attach it.  I feel really stupid for asking this, it's probably really easy but how would I do that?  First, I only have 500 characters and it is about 3 times that length.  Second, the formatting is not retained when I copy and paste.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @whatsherface -- You can "edit" your original post and copy/paste it in there. The formatting for code isn't retained unless you prefix each line with 4 spaces, so it's probably easiest to try to figure out what part of your script isn't working and for each part that isn't working, post a new question.  As with all programming, this sort of thing is usually best done in chunks.

Comment: I have attached the code. Sorry it's so long but I really have no idea where the problems are arising. I usually don't solve problems this way, I'm all about figuring stuff out on my own but I've not been finding the documentation very helpful.

Comment: @whatsherface -- your code looks mostly alright.  I've made a few comments above which will hopefully be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I should have made a better explanation though. The first line I should have left off because I am actually just manually specifying the data file since it changes. The 2nd line with the // is just psuedo-code b/c that part is lengthy. The script actually runs fine, I guess my only question is how do I place a label in the bottom left corner of the page given this particular script that I have.

Comment: @whatsherface `set label 1 "my label says foo" at screen .1,.1`  -- add it just before your final plot command.  In the future, it's typically good practice to open a new question rather than stringing a whole bunch together in comments.  This one could be called "How do I position a label in gnuplot relative to the edge of the canvas" -- or something like that.

Comment: My question never changed, I just should have said "label" in the question instead of "title". I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thank you again for all your help. I think I can figure it out from here.

Comment: @whatsherface : Glad to help.  Feel free to keep posting questions here.  The SO community at large is pretty friendly I think.